# Separate overlapping polygons into regions

Tags: python

I cam across the following post under Stack Overflow: [Exploding overlapping polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32217/exploding-overlapping-to-new-non-overlapping-polygons)

I downloaded the source code that was posted by the initial author of the post and made adjustments trying to get it to work, but I'm currently receiving the following error message and not sure how to resolve it, please be advised that I'm still learning to code, so I'm lacking fundamental theory.

[image: Error Message: When running the attached code]

Error Message: Text

> Executing: OverlapReg
>   E:\Projects\2015\H111225_6\ArcHydro\27Jan15\01SouthNorthAlign\OverlappingWatershedsAnalysis.gdb\Watershed
>   HydroID2 Start Time: Wed Mar 11 14:58:32 2015 Running script
>   OverlapReg... Failed script OverlapReg...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Python\Masters\Scripts\OverlappingRegions\OverlappingRegions.py",
>   line 59, in 
>       countOverlaps(fc,idName)   File "E:\Python\Masters\Scripts\OverlappingRegions\OverlappingRegions.py",
>   line 58, in countOverlaps
>       urows.updateRow(urow)   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line
>   102, in updateRow
>       return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.UpdateRow(*gp_fixargs(args)))
>   RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function. The row contains
>   a bad value. [Watershed] The row contains a bad value. [overlaps]
>
> Failed to execute (OverlapReg). Failed at Wed Mar 11 14:58:35 2015
>   (Elapsed Time: 2.45 seconds)

I'm trying to assign id's to my Watershed Feature Class based on the following code to be able to split my Watershed Feature Class into the least amount of separate feature classes where the Watersheds don't overlap each other, as I need to export them into a AutoCAD drawing where there are not overlapping features within a single layer.

```
import os
import arcpy

from arcpy import GetParameterAsText

fc = GetParameterAsText(0)
idName = GetParameterAsText(1)

dirname = os.path.dirname(arcpy.Describe(fc).catalogPath)
desc = arcpy.Describe(dirname)
if hasattr(desc, "datasetType") and desc.datasetType=='FeatureDataset':
    dirname = os.path.dirname(dirname)

arcpy.env.workspace = dirname

def countOverlaps(fc,idName):
    intersect = arcpy.Intersect_analysis(fc,'intersect')
    findID = arcpy.FindIdentical_management(intersect,"explFindID","Shape")
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(intersect,"intlyr")
    arcpy.AddJoin_management("intlyr",arcpy.Describe("intlyr").OIDfieldName,findID,"IN_FID","KEEP_ALL")
    segIDs = {}
    featseqName = "explFindID.FEAT_SEQ"
    idNewName = "intersect."+idName

    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("intlyr"):
        idVal = row.getValue(idNewName)
        featseqVal = row.getValue(featseqName)
        segIDs[featseqVal] = []
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("intlyr"):
        idVal = row.getValue(idNewName)
        featseqVal = row.getValue(featseqName)
        segIDs[featseqVal].append(idVal)

    segIDs2 = {}
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("intlyr"):
        idVal = row.getValue(idNewName)
        segIDs2[idVal] = []

    for x,y in segIDs.iteritems():
        for segID in y:
            segIDs2[segID].extend([k for k in y if k != segID])

    for x,y in segIDs2.iteritems():
        segIDs2[x] = list(set(y))

    arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("intlyr",arcpy.Describe(findID).name)

    if 'overlaps' not in [k.name for k in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc,'overlaps',"TEXT")
    if 'ovlpCount' not in [k.name for k in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]:
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc,'ovlpCount',"SHORT")

    urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
    for urow in urows:
        idVal = urow.getValue(idName)
        if segIDs2.get(idVal):
            urow.overlaps = str(segIDs2[idVal]).strip('[]')
            urow.ovlpCount = len(segIDs2[idVal])
        urows.updateRow(urow)
countOverlaps(fc,idName)

def explodeOverlaps(fc,idName):

    countOverlaps(fc,idName)

    arcpy.AddField_management(fc,'expl',"SHORT")

    urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc,'"overlaps" IS NULL')
    for urow in urows:
        urow.expl = 1
        urows.updateRow(urow)

    i=1
    lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc)
    while int(arcpy.GetCount_management(arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,"NEW_SELECTION",'"expl" IS NULL')).getOutput(0)) > 0:
        ovList=[]
        urows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc,'"expl" IS NULL','','','ovlpCount D')
        for urow in urows:
            ovVal = urow.overlaps
            idVal = urow.getValue(idName)
            intList = ovVal.replace(' ','').split(',')
            for x in intList:
                intList[intList.index(x)] = int(x)
            if idVal not in ovList:
                urow.expl = i
            urows.updateRow(urow)
            ovList.extend(intList)
        i+=1
explodeOverlaps(fc,idName)
```

Any assistance in how to resolve the following will truly be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the full **text** of the error message, not an image.

Comment: @MattDMo Please let me know if the following is suitable:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clues are in the errors.

> the row contains a bad value [Watershed]
>
> the row contains a bad value [overlaps]

This is likely cause by trying to insert a value into the field *overlaps*, but due to something with the field properties like the length is 4 and your value is "long string", it therefore is too big to be inserted.

[ESRI](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37826)

[GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31042/insert-cursor-row-contains-a-bad-value)

Comment: Thanks Tony, the problem was that the IdName was being inserted into the Overlaps field for each Watershed that was being overlapped and my ID's start at 10000. The field length was set to 255 characters and I needed 815. I've reduced my ID's to thousand to resolve the following.